# ApacheDS upgrade/backup/restore problems

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

Ubuntu 14.04
ApacheDS 2.0.0-M21
Apache Directory Studio 2.0

I was trying to upgrade to ApacheDS 2.0.0-M23 with no success.
It requires some backup/restore procedures but I have not found anything in ApacheDS documentation on how to do it. All my attempts to work with LDIF export/import have failed. Even when I exported a configuration it refused to import the output file complaining that it doesn't seem a correct LDIF file.

They provide upgrades without any explanations on how to apply them.

Any thoughts on that?

Update.

I have found the only way to import/ldapadd ApacheDS ldif dump file and it is using ldapadd with -c or 'Continue on error' in Apache Directory Studio. After running import/ldapadd in my case 3 times the ldif file was imported/added. I am not sure that this approach is suitable for a production environment.

Comment: Hi - I'm having similar issues. Wondering if you've found a permanent solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a full dump with the -LLL switch. Set the dump to only include the OU's that you want to restore - don't get the ou=system stuff for instance.

Comment: Have you tried this on ApacheDS 2.0.0-M21/M23? I am going back to openLDAP.

Comment: Should work for any true LDAP server - I have done it from OpenLDAP _to_ ApacheDS but not the other way around. I've also dumped several AD domains into ApacheDS this way.

Comment: TheFiddlerWins. It looks like what you have done is a one-way road. I have also successfully moved from openLDAP to ApacheDS. ApacheDS creates a dump files with the wrong order of entries/attributes in a result ldif file. That is why those ldif files can't be ldapadd'ed or Apache Directory Studio's imported. At least this is what I am experiencing with ApacheDS 2.0.0-M21. openLDAP creates dump ldif in the correct order of all entries.